# Queuing or allowing multiple AJAX requests in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, radajaxmanager

I've got the following scenario:

User has the ability to drag-and-drop a control onto the page. The 'dropping' client-side event initaties an ajaxRequest like so:

```
function OnClientDropping(sender, eventArgs) {
    var sourceItem = eventArgs.get_sourceItem();
    var droppedID = eventArgs.get_htmlElement().id;

    if (droppedID.indexOf("RadDockZone") != -1) {
        if ($find(droppedID).get_docks().length == 0) {
            var eventData = {};
            eventData["sourceItemText"] = sourceItem.get_text();
            eventData["sourceItemValue"] = sourceItem.get_value();
            eventData["listBoxID"] = sender.get_id();

            $find(ajaxManagerID).ajaxRequestWithTarget(droppedID, $.toJSON(eventData));
    }
}
```

Now, while this ajaxRequest is processing, the user still has full control over their mouse. It would not be an uncommon scenario for them to wish to drag-and-drop another control onto the page while this event is still processing.

Currently, if they do just that, the first event gets cancelled and then the second event runs successfully. I was wondering how I could queue these events up?

I tried simply wrapping the above code in "$.queue($find(ajaxManagerID).....)", but I did not notice any changes in how my project ran.

What's the proper way to support this scenario?

```
if (queue.length == 0) {
    queue.push(uniqueDockZoneID);
    queue.push(eventData);
    $find(ajaxManagerID).ajaxRequestWithTarget(uniqueDockZoneID, $.toJSON(eventData));
}
else {
    queue.push(uniqueDockZoneID);
    queue.push(eventData);
}

function endRequest(sender, eventArgs) {

    if (queue.length > 0) {
        queue.shift(); //Remove the ID of the control we just finished.
        queue.shift(); //Remove the data for the control we just finished.
    }

    //If we've got more ajax requests queued up.
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        uniqueDockZoneID = queue.shift();
        data = queue.shift();
        $find(ajaxManagerID).ajaxRequestWithTarget(uniqueDockZoneID, $.toJSON(data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add the uniqueId and the dockZoneID into an array and then remove each item from the array as the associated ajax request gets completed?

Comment: Sorry, I think my example is poor. Let me edit the code slightly. I am not attempting to update two items in one ajaxRequest. The whole function is getting called again by an independent item later on.

Comment: I still think you can use an array to manage your pending requests

Comment: Perhaps I am confused. Are you suggesting storing an outside-of-scope array, pushing droppedID into the array, and then executing the ajax request after popping the first element from the array? I feel like jQuery's fx queue was created for this purpose? I should be able to push the ajax request into this queue, no?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not working, so I'm providing an alternative. Perhaps this solution is more simple than jQuery's queue.

Comment: Indeed. So, lemme flesh this out. I keep an array, first drop event happens, push element into array and start the ajax request. Second drop event happens, I push the element into the array. Now, loop, waiting until the first element in the array is the one just pushed into the array. When it sees 'itself' then the ajaxRequest fires?

Comment: yeah... thinking out loud here: first drop event happens, push element into array start ajax request #1. Ajax Request #1 finishes, removes its id from array, checks for more elements in array, if so, call ajax request #2, otherwise, finished. Key is, every drop event checks to see if array is empty, if so, add to array process ajax request, if not _only_ add to array. You can have a method called ajaxIsRunning() that returns array.length > 0; (true or false)

Comment: I went ahead and sketched out some rough code in an edit of my main post. Is this about what you were thinking? It seems right, going to go test it out..

Comment: queue.pop will remove the last one, make sure you are removing the one that corresponds to the current request - and even then only after it's been completed (in case it fails for some reason)

Comment: Nice. It worked. I'll edit my original post. Thank you for your help, sorry if I came off as short. :)